# Linear regression prediction model in Python using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, linear-regression, spyder

Here is my **sample data**:

```
import pandas as pd

avg_consumption = pd.DataFrame({
'Car.Year.Model':[2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
'City.mpg':[17.9, 17, 16.9, 18.3],
'Highway.mpg':[24.3, 23.6, 23.6, 25.7]
})
```

I want to use Linear Regression to predict the average fuel consumptions for each fuel range type (city and highway) per car model year.

**My desired output** is my same DataFrame but where it has predicted the average fuel consumption for car model years up to 2025 using my existing data.
I am not entirely sure how to go about this.

**What I have tried:**

I attempted to follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623171/simple-prediction-using-linear-regression-with-python) as the question seemed similar:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

years = pd.DataFrame()
years['Car.Year.Model'] = range(2009, 2025)
# I include 2009-2012 to test the prediction values are still the same as the original

X = avg_consumption.filter(['Car.Year.Model'])
y = avg_consumption.drop('Car.Year.Model', axis=1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

X_predict = years
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
```

**My result** is the following:

[image]

If I assume that my first row has the predicted values for 2009, it is incorrect because the values in my original DataFrame for model year 2009 are different.

**I want to make sure it is predicting the average fuel consumption correctly for each year up to 2025.** I would also like my results presented in a DataFrame similar to my sample data.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "it is incorrect because the values in my original DataFrame for model year 2009 are different.": that is because your (input) values are the actual data, but this dataframe has predictions from a best-fit model. The output is not your data: it's basically a line through some scatter points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and [numpy.poly1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) for the linear extrapolation. And then add the projected years like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

avg_consumption = pd.DataFrame({
'Car.Year.Model':[2009, 2010, 2011, 2012],
'City.mpg':[17.9, 17, 16.9, 18.3],
'Highway.mpg':[24.3, 23.6, 23.6, 25.7]
})

f_city = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(avg_consumption["Car.Year.Model"], avg_consumption["City.mpg"], 1))
f_highway = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(avg_consumption["Car.Year.Model"], avg_consumption["Highway.mpg"], 1))
new_data = pd.DataFrame([[i, f_city(i), f_highway(i)] for i in range(2013, 2026)], columns=avg_consumption.columns)
avg_consumption = pd.concat([avg_consumption, new_data], axis=0)
```

Yields:

```
    Car.Year.Model  City.mpg  Highway.mpg
0             2009     17.90        24.30
1             2010     17.00        23.60
2             2011     16.90        23.60
3             2012     18.30        25.70
0             2013     17.80        25.35
1             2014     17.91        25.77
2             2015     18.02        26.19
3             2016     18.13        26.61
4             2017     18.24        27.03
5             2018     18.35        27.45
6             2019     18.46        27.87
7             2020     18.57        28.29
8             2021     18.68        28.71
9             2022     18.79        29.13
10            2023     18.90        29.55
11            2024     19.01        29.97
12            2025     19.12        30.39
```

```
ax = avg_consumption.set_index("Car.Year.Model").iloc[:4].plot()
avg_consumption.set_index("Car.Year.Model").iloc[3:].plot(ls="-.", ax=ax)
```

[image]