# How do I use the linear regression coefficients to come up with a value of a used car?

Tags: python, linear-regression, predict

**Goal:**

I want to predict car prices using linear regression on the following used car prices data:

[image: data]

**My Procedure:**

I one hot encoded 'Make' and 'Type', and added those columns back in:

[image: data after OHE]

I then used standard scalar on my predictor columns:

[image: scaled predictors]

**My Model:**

I used OLS (after adding a constant) to get the coefficients:

[image: OLS coefficients]

**Question:**
Using this how do I predict, for example: a Cadillac sedan with leather with 6 cylinders and 45000 miles on it?

I'm familiar with using ss.transform to get the scaled values, which I can then feed into `model_OLS.predict` to predict the car price. I'm guessing I can't just pick and choose which features I want to use to predict the price? I have to state all of them?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, where is your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple prediction using linear regression with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623171/simple-prediction-using-linear-regression-with-python)

Comment: @martineau, I did a simpler model with only 3 features, and I used ss.transform and OLS.predict to get a car price. It was easier with just 3 features. With more features, and wanting to only use some of them to predict, I didn't know how to use the method I did above- I didn't know how to let the functions know which features I'm using. I hope that make sense.

I appreciate the understanding though, and sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Jared: I did look at that post prior to posting my question, however they're only using one feature.

Comment: My understanding is, I can either manually use the coefs I'm interested in to predict a car price, OR do a new model using just the features I want. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Making predictions with limited features does not make much sense if you have fitted the OLS model on all of the features. You could perhaps cherry pick the coefficients (const + 1*Make_Cadillac + 1*Leather + 6*Cylinder) for a custom prediction, or you could just re-fit the model on the features you want to use in making a prediction, perhaps wrapping in a function to streamline it.

```
vals = {'Make_Cadillac': 1, 'Leather': 1, 'Cylinder': 6} # populate scaled values instead or transform them in the function

def make_prediction(X, y, vals):
    OLS = sm.OLS(y, X[[*vals]]).fit()
    # scale input values #
    return OLS.predict([*vals.values()])

print(make_prediction(X, y, vals))
```

Comment: I see. Thanks! I wanted to see if I could use multiple features in the model but only use some of the features to predict a car price via code. I did a simpler model with only 3 features and was able to use ss.transform and OLS.predict to come up with a car price, but it was simpler.